# Database Design: how to associate car colors? Associate it to its make or trim?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a project that deals with cars. I need to know if a car's color selection is based on the "model" or the "trim." For example, does the "2011 nissan sentra" have a list of available colors for all its trims? Or does the "2011 nissan sentra LX" have a list of available colors for just that trim (in this example, the "LX") and that other trims would have different color options?

Comment: This sounds like more of a car question than a programming one

Comment: That depends on manufacturer, and model year.  But the VIN does specify color.  There may be a guarantee that in 2012 Volkswagen only makes its Golf GTI in four colors, which may be different from the base Golf colors.  But that guarantee might not hold for Subaru, and if it does, it will change yearly ... sometimes even mid-model year.

Comment: Note that questions about database design is usually most welcome here, questions about the world you're modelling, unless that world is related to programming, is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's just called the "trim". For example: http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/nissan/sentra/price#features

It says there are 5 trim options, even though the next page shows 6, but if you surf around for other cars, the trim numbers usually match up with the color options.

Not necessarily related, but I did also come across this: http://www.paintscratch.com/search.html Use the second search box and try something simple like "red"